# What Statistical Test to use to determine significant difference between ordinal variables pre and post intervention

Tags: statistical-significance, paired-data

I have a variable that has 4 levels low, med, high, very high. The variable is from two time points, in 2013 and 2019, assessed using the same survey on the same subject/study individuals. I'm struggling to figure out exactly how to compare these. Is there a way to compare the variables as a whole? or do I compare the individual levels eg high 2013 vs high 2019? and what test would be best?
180 subjects, and the counts were recorded at each of the 4 levels eg:
2013 cleanliness: low=20 med=40 high=90 very high=30   and
2019 cleanliness: low=10 med=80 high=70 very high=20
I was considering a chi square test, but they aren't independent.
paired T test is likely also a no go?
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: it seems chi squared should be ok

Comment: I see no clear path to a relevant chi-squared test of a table based on the counts given. Data seem to be paired between the two years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I imagine your data set:

You have two dependent groups and measured cleanliness as an ordinal variable from let's say 1 = low to 4 = very high.

```
> data <- list(first = c(rep(1,20), rep(2, 40), rep(3, 90), rep(4, 30)), 
second = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 80), rep(3, 70), rep(4, 20)))
```

In R you could do the sign test for this with the function `signt` from the Wilcox Robust Statistics (WRS) package:

```
# load the package
> source("https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/239/docs/Rallfun-v38.txt")

> signt(as.data.frame(data))

$Prob_x_less_than_y
[1] 0.2

$ci
[1] 0.1105025 0.3323061

$n
[1] 180

$N
[1] 50

$p.value
[1] 0.001
```

The `signt` function tests H0: p = 0.5. You see we can reject and see that it is more likely to observe a higher value in the first group than in the second because p = 0.2 which is lower than 0.5. The confidence interval does not contain p = 0.5 so we can conclude that the groups differ significantly.
A disadvantage of this test is that if we have tied values like in this example, the sign test deals with them by ignoring them. This leaves us with a sample of just 50 observations.

If you want more power you can also use the improved Friedman test by Brunner et al. for two or more dependent groups accessible through the function `bprm`. Tied values are handled as midranks in this case and you see the p-value is lower. A disadvantage is that it just tells you that there is a difference but nothing else:

```
> bprm(data)
$test.stat
[1] 31.36682

$nu1
[1] 1

$p.value
[1] 2.136558e-08
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try it out! A follow up question, There are about 30 variables with a similar situation. However there are a few occasions when a) the denominator isn't the same for the two time periods (eg 2 subjects could not be assessed in 2019 for a certain variable) b) when the denominator is the same (180 both years) but there are only three groups ie not one recording for very high in 2019. Is there a sensible way to deal with these?

Comment: While the Sign Test tests the overall probability of each observation in group one being lower than in group two, the Brunner's improved Friedman test tests whether distributions of the groups differ. Hence to answer a) the Sign Test requires equal group sizes while the latter test does not. Concerning b) for both tests it is irrelevant whether your highest value is 3, 4 or 500.

Comment: Thanks again Jan, this has been amazing, seems to be working well. So as your previous answer it allows us to assess if there is a significant difference in the variable as a whole but not necessarily at the individual levels, is that correct? Is there a straightforward way for me to assess the significance say at for example the changes to the medium level 40 to 80?

Comment: Yes both tests test whether the cleanliness rating as a dependent variable significantly differs between year 2013 and 2019 (independent variable). The advantage of the sign test is that it tells that we are more likely to observe higher cleanliness ratings in the year 2013 than 2019. The latter test just tells you that cleanliness ratings do differ significantly between the two years. I don't know about a test that would explicitly test whether e.g. the medium ratings differ significantly between dependent groups.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we know that 120 subjects gave the same rating in the two years,
10 gave higher ratings the 2nd year and 40 gave lower ratings the second year. Then there were 50 changes of which 40 were lower
and 10 were higher. [For an an analysis of your data, you would have to make a careful tally, not available from the information given.]

A sign test would be appropriate: The null hypothesis is no change.
If a fair coin is tossed 50 times what is the probability it will show 10 heads and 40 tails. The P-value is the probability (near $0)$ of
getting a more extreme count (from 25) in either direction by chance alone, than
was observed. So the null hypothesis of no significant change is rejected.

```
 sum(dbinom(0:10, 50, .5)) + sum(dbinom(40:50, 50, .5))
 [1] 2.386133e-05
```

In the plot below, the P-value is the sum of the heights of the bars
in the two tails beyond the vertical dotted lines.

[image]

```
x = 0:50;  PDF = dbinom(x, 50, .5)
plot(x, PDF, type="h", lwd=2, col="blue", main = "BINOM(50,.5)")
abline(h = 0, col="green2")
abline(v = 0, col="green2")
abline(v = c(10.5, 39.5), col="red", lty="dotted")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you could think of this in terms of a multinomial logistic regression with repeated measurements.  If you used a cumulative logit link function you would have one have one regression parameter to interpret for 2019 vs 2013.  If you used a generalized logit you would have a separate 2019 vs 2013 comparison for each level: low, med, high, very high. Using standard software the test and confidence interval method would be a Wald test on the cumulative or generalized logit scale that accounts for the correlation between repeated measurements on the same subject.

Comment: Yes the proportional odds model is a good basis for this and handles extreme ties in the data.   Not clear on how you model the correlation.